# Vector Operations in C while calling a file

Tags: arrays, c

We have been asked to do the following; however, I am new to coding and facing few difficulties. I have attached my code below which is throwing multiple errors. Can someone please help?

Description -------------------------------------------------------------

Write a C function named "VectorOperations", which

1. takes as its input an integer named "size", which specifies the sizes of two float arrays. If the size is invalid, print "Invalid Size" otherwise it executes the following steps.
2. reads two arrays from the input file named "vectors.txt", which is located in the current directory (where your C file is located). The input file must be formatted as below (each row represents an array and each array member is separated from others by a single space):

0.75 0.95 0.98 0.88 0.51

0.91 0.43 0.56 1.02 1.03

3. computes the dot product of the two arrays (vectors).
4. computes the maximum of the two arrays (the largest member among the members of both arrays).
5. writes the dot product and the maximum into a file named "results.txt" as listed below (please strictly follow the output format; there are 40 '-' characters at each separating line. also the numbers have exactly 2 decimal places):

### Print in this form-->

Operations: Dot Product and Maximum

---

Here's my code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int vectors;
int main ()
{
int readFile(void){
    FILE *VectorOperations;        /* a file stream variable */
    char fileName[] = "vectors.txt"; /* a c-string */
    char chunk[100];
    vectors = fopen(fileName, "r" ); // open for reading and writing, overwriting a file
    if(vectors == NULL ) /*check for file open errors*/
    {
        printf("Invalid Size");
        return -1;  /* terminate the program */
    }
    else
    {
         /* write data to the file */
        for(int i=0; i<40; i++) fprintf(VectorOperations, "-");
        fprintf(VectorOperations, "\nSUM %s\n");
        for(int i=0; i<40; i++) fprintf(VectorOperations, "-");
        fgets(chunk, sizeof(chunk), vectors);
        fgets(chunk, sizeof(chunk), vectors);
        fgets(chunk, sizeof(chunk), vectors);
        fgets(chunk, sizeof(chunk), vectors);
        printf("%s", chunk);

        fclose(VectorOperations);    /* close the file stream */
        return 0;
}
// ---------------------------------------------------------
int Tutorial4_run(void){
    writeFile();
    readFile();
    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}



int writeFile(){
    FILE *VectorOperations;        /* a file stream variable */
    
    char fileName[] = "vectors.txt"; /* a c-string */
    char size[] = "size";       /* a c-string */
    VectorOperations = fopen(fileName, "w" ); // open for writing, overwriting a file
    if(VectorOperations == NULL ) /*check for file open errors*/
    {
        fprintf("Invalid Size");
        return -1;  /* terminate the program */
    }
    else
    {
        /* write data to the file */
        for(int i=0; i<40; i++) fprintf(VectorOperations, "-");
        fprintf(VectorOperations, "\nsize %s\n", size);
        for(int i=0; i<40; i++) fprintf(VectorOperations, "-");
        fgets(chunk, sizeof(chunk), vectors);
        fgets(chunk, sizeof(chunk), vectors);
        fgets(chunk, sizeof(chunk), vectors);
        fgets(chunk, sizeof(chunk), vectors);
        printf("%s", chunk);

        fclose(VectorOperations);    /* close the file stream */
        return 0;
    }
}

}
```

Comment: Explain the difficulties you're having and add any errors you're receiving to your question.

Comment: Standard C does not have the concept of "nested functions"; your compiler may have as an extension. To write a portable program do not define functions inside functions.

Comment: ... and replace `vectors = fopen(fileName, "r" );` with `VectorOperations = fopen(fileName, "r" );`

Comment: In `readFile()`, it should be `vectors = fopen = fopen` instead of `vectors = fopen`. Also, you probably need to use some function such as `fgets` or another function to get the size from the user and store it in `vectors`.

Comment: This code is very far away from a correct working program. Break the problem into much simpler tasks snd get them working separately before you try putting them together. Try opening a file a copying its contents to standard output. Then try reading numbers from a file. Then try saving numbers in an array. Then try finding the maximum. And so on. Overall, this problem looks a little too advanced for the state of learning suggested by the code in the question.

Comment: @RetiredNinja - I would like to read the file on my computer(which has the array data) then if the data size is equal, multiply them and write a new file named 'results'.

Comment: @EricPostpischil - I know. It's a bit over my level. But thank you for your suggestion. I will give it a go the way you mentioned. 

Thanks a lot.

Comment: @KevalPatel You're just repeating the requirements already in the question. The requirements are useful because the goal is important, but you need to explain specifically what you're having trouble with getting to that goal. You also mentioned multiple errors but didn't include them in the question. Assuming you'd like to understand and fix those we need to see them.